# Minimize Number of Queries in Django Model Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Suppose I have two models ModelA, ModelB,

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    # multple model fields, also contains foreign key
    
class Model2(models.Model):
    model1_id = models.ForeignKey(Model1, models.DO_NOTHING)
    # other model fields
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.ForeignKey()
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field4 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

admin file for Model1 like,

```
@admin.register(Model1)
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_per_page = 10

    list_display = ['some_model1_fields', 'get_field1','get_field2', 'get_field3', 'get_field4']

    def get_field1(self, obj):
        return obj.model2_set.last().field1

    def get_field2(self, obj):
        return obj.model2_set.last().field2

    def get_field3(self, obj):
        return obj.model2_set.last().field3

    def get_field4(self, obj):
        return obj.model2_set.last().field4
```

when I get related model fields using method in list_display, it repeats same query multiple time (list_per_page * no_of_fields_by_method which is 40 in current case).

**I don't want to join model1 with model2 because model1 already join with other models and we know Count() query will takes time if we have large tables.**

My question is , Is any other way to get releted model objects without repeat the same query? (means only 10 times query instead of 40 times same query in current case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure, if the admin passes the same object `obj` to the methods (`def get_field1(self, obj):`), but if it does, then you could try using the [`cached_property` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property).

In models add a method with this decorator, so that this method will query the database only once for the lifetime of this object:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    @cached_property
    def cached_last_model2(self):
        return self.model2_set.last()
```

and try using this in the admin:

```
@admin.register(Model1)
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_field1(self, obj):
        return obj.cached_last_model2.field1

    def get_field2(self, obj):
        return obj.cached_last_model2.field2
    ...
```